# How do we place dockers on chosen servers?

Tags: docker, architecture, administration

In short, we have the following problem: we have too many grabbers, websites, libraries, zabbix etc. that need to be deployed quickly, preferably with a single or just few clicks, on our servers.
For that, we chose docker. But how do we place these dockers on chosen servers? And how do we quickly transfer it to another server?
Ideally, we require some sort of programming complex or software package that will allow us to quickly move one docker to another server with a single command. And so it would support configs like:
program install --config config.yml

So it'd take servers out of a config, all the stuff required for access, and then would install it. I'll keep this config on GIT and will edit it when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) is the standard solution for dealing with this at scale.  It is a robust system with lots of tools/apis to manage/scale docker containers and manage fleets of servers.

Also, look at [helm](https://helm.sh/) for your deployment to standardize the deployment process.